# query date table in php and passing it to php date object in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to query a table using php and want to pass that value to the date object in javascript,php query is working fine but don't know how to pass it to date object as i have to set a probation period say 2 months form post date.

```
?php echo $this->translate('Created %s', $this->timestamp($this->group->creation_date)) ?>
```

This works fine,but i want to pass it to date object in javascript

```
var target_date = new Date();

target_date.setDate(target_date.getDate() + 1 /*days*/);
```

i want to pass creation date to target_date of javascript.
Help will really be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in following way .

```
<?php $date =   $this->translate('Created %s', $this->timestamp($this->group->creation_date)); 
?>

<script>
 var target_date = "<?php echo $date; ?>"; 
 target_date.setDate(target_date.getDate() + 1 /*days*/)
<script>
```